# Passing vatiable between windows in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have made an Electron App, with a index.js, app.js, index.html and gas.html, gas.js. What I am trying to do is basically this,

In index.html I have a select:

```html
<body>
    <h1>WIN</h1>
    <select id="testSelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btn">BTN</button>
</body>
```

In app.js when I press a button, a new Window opens up (gas.html), in that window i want to show the value i selected in index.html

This is index.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

let win = null;
let win2 = null;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 780,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'static/icon.png'),
        show: false,
        resizable: true
    });

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show()
    });

    //win.removeMenu();
    //win.webContents.openDevTools();
    
}

ipcMain.on('select-value',(event, data) => {
    console.log(data)
})

ipcMain.on('openPage', async (_, arg) => {
    if (!win2) {

        win2 = new BrowserWindow({
            parent: win,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            },
            frame: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 780,
            show: false
        });

        //win2.maximize();

        win2.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, arg.page),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }));

        win2.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            win2.show()
        });

        win2.on('close', _ => { win2 = null });

        //win2.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
});

ipcMain.on('closePage', _ => {
    win2.close();
});

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

if (!gotTheLock) {
    app.quit();
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
        if (win) {
            if (win.isMinimized()) {
                win.restore();
            }
            win.focus();
        }
    })

    // This method will be called when Electron has finished
    // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
    // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
    app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

    // Quit when all windows are closed.
    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
        // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
        // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            app.quit();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried doing this in app.js, and I recieve the data in index.js, but then I cannot send it to the other page that should open (the commented line):

```js
const { ipcRenderer, powerMonitor } = require('electron');
const ADODB = require('node-adodb');

$("#btn").on('click', () => {
    console.log($('#testSelect').val())
    ipcRenderer.send('select-value', $('#testSelect').val())
    //ipcRenderer.send('openPage', {page: 'gas.html'})
})
```

Finally what I need is:

1. Start app (win appears), select a value from $('#testSelect')
2. After a button is pressed, new window appears (win2)
3. In that window the selected value gets showed

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beginners, Electron communications between the main process and render process(es) can be difficult to understand.

I suggest you fully read and understand the below Electron topics to get a full appreciation on how everything works together.

- [Process Model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model)
- [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)
- [Context Bridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)
- [Using Preload Scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)
- [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)
- [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)
- [Webcontents Send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)

Your `index.html` and `index.js` (which I assume should be `app.js`) files appear to be well-formed and spot on when creating your second window within the `ipcMain.on('openPage')` method.

Your pain point is how to transfer the `testSelect` value from window 1 to window 2. This can be achieved during the creation of window 2.

That said, your `index.js` file could do with some minor tidy-up such as:

- Use of [`win.loadFile(filePath[, option])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) in place of [`win.loadURL(url[, options])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options).

---

In the minimum reproducible example below, I have included all the necessary files to demonstrate how to integrate your services together.

### In a brief outline:

In the `app.js` file, this is where both our windows are created.

`window1` is created and shown when the application starts.

`window2` is created after receiving an IPC message (`openWindow2`) from the `window1`render process.

Just prior to `show()`ing `window2`, we send an IPC message containing the `testSelect` value on the `sendData` channel.

Within the `<script>` tags of `window2`, we receive the `testSelect` value on the `sendData` channel and then populate the disabled input with the value.

> Note: I have renamed your `index.html` and `gas.html` files to `index1.html` and `index2.html` for the sake of simplicity. Additionally, for brevity, I have wrapped any Javascript into the `<script>` tags of these files.

---

`app.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window1;
let window2;

function createWindow1() {
    const window1 = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window1.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'index1.html'))
        .then(() => { window1.show(); });

    return window1;
}

function createWindow2(testSelect) {
    const window2 = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window2.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'index2.html'))
        .then(() => { window2.webContents.send('sendData', testSelect); }) // Send data to window 2
        .then(() => { window2.show(); });

    return window2;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window1 = createWindow1();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow1();
    }
});

//---

electronIpcMain.on('openWindow2', (event, testSelect) => {
    console.log(testSelect); // Testing
    window2 = createWindow2(testSelect);
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels
const ipc = {
    'channels': {
        // From render to main
        'send': [
            'openWindow2'
        ],
        // From main to render
        'receive': [
            'sendData'
        ],
        // From main to render (once)
        'receiveOnce': [],
        // From render to main and back again
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        send: (channel, args) => {
            if (ipc.channels.send.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            if (ipc.channels.receive.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From main to render (once)
        receiveOnce: (channel, listener) => {
            if (ipc.channels.receiveOnce.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.once(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            if (ipc.channels.sendReceive.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And how to use the `preload.js` script in more detail.

```txt
/**
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Main --> Render (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.receiveOnce('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Render --> Main (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.once('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await myPromise(data)
 *                  .then((result) => { return result; })
 *          });
 *
 * Main:    function myPromise(data) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }); }
 *
 */
```

---

`index1.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Window 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Window 1</h1>

        <label for="testSelect">Test Select: </label>

        <select id="testSelect">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <hr>

        <input type="button" id="button" value="Button">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let testSelect = document.getElementById('testSelect').value;

            console.log(testSelect); // Testing
            window.ipcRenderer.send('openWindow2', testSelect);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`index2.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Window 2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Window 2</h1>

        <label for="testSelect">Test Select Output: </label>

        <input type="text" id="testSelect" disabled>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.ipcRenderer.receive('sendData', (testSelect) => {
            console.log(testSelect); // Testing
            document.getElementById('testSelect').value = testSelect;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```